# How can I use create a bridge network for different VLANs so my host + guest can connect to different VLANs?

Tags: networkmanager, kvm, libvirt, virt-manager, vlan

My box has Debian 12, KDE, and is using Network Manager.

I am using virt-manager and want to create VMs on different VLANs on my network.

My box is connected to a port on my switch that allows VLAN 10 and 20.

I figured out how to create a bridge network from the Network Manager GUI (`plasma-nm`) (screenshots below)

1. disalbe auto connect for my default/main/physical ethernet (`LAN` => `eno1`)
2. create a new bridged network, add ethernet that is restricted to `eno1`, disable STP

What I can't figure out is bridge + VLANs. I want:

1. my host to join VLAN 10
2. some VMs on 10
3. some VMs on 20

for this to work, I assume (????) I need 2 bridged connections:

1. one for VLAN 10 that my host and VMs will use
2. one for VLAN 20 that VMs will use

Is this right? How do I configure this from the GUI?

## My default wired connection set to not auto connect

[image]

## New bridged connection

[image]

## New bridged connection connections

[image]

## New bridged connection restricted to eno1

[image]